# up/down & f1-12 keys are disabled

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot pc with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.4.2. I cannot leave the Ubuntu Os for a live boot(tails) or use my windows Os because the up/down & f1-12 keys are disabled at the Ubuntu grub boot screen.Which Os to boot into just times out and boots into Ubuntu.My keyboard is the Usb type so i have moved it around but no change. Can anyone suggest anything to fix this please.Thanks.

Comment: Does it work to access and within BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: No i cannot enter bios.I usually press f12 to enter bios but its as though all f keys are disabled. Im stuck on Ubuntu.

Comment: True but it has nothing to do with Ubuntu. If it's an old PC with PS/2 ports for keyboard/mouse you may need to use a PS/2 keyboard or (USB > PS/2) adapter to finally access BIOS and enable support for USB keyboards. If not an old PC then please [edit] and post the brand/model.

Comment: The Pc is a Zoostorm 2Tb Intel 16gb about 5 years old. It came with Usb mouse and keyboard. Ive used the f12 keys to boot into other Os and always had no issue. I am sure it started after i installed Ubuntu18 recently.

Comment: I will get a wireless battery op keyboard and see if its personal to this keyboard or system wide. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My wireless keyboard makes no difference.Grub is stuck at first option -Ubuntu. I cannot even boot into a live usb because f12 does not get me into bios to change boot order. Im stuck on Ubuntu.